# Cakephp Multiple File Upload

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to create a multiple file upload using cakephp. However, I bumped into a problem wherein I could not enable the "multiple" functionality of the built in upload function of cake.

Here's what I got:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Cmt', array('type'=>'file','multiple'=>'multiple'));
    echo $this->Form->file('File');
    echo $this->Form->submit('Upload');
    echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Best solution is

```
echo $this->Form->file('File. ', array('type'=>'file','multiple'=>'multiple'));
```

Comment: Yes. Adding a dot '.' like 'File. ' in the end of the name shows all the images selected.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake lies in this line of code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Cmt', array('type'=>'file','multiple'=>'multiple'));
```

Upon research, I was able to get the right one and modified my code into this:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Cmt');
    echo $this->Form->file('File', array('type'=>'file','multiple'=>'multiple'));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Upload');
    echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

got it working  :)